# Convert postgres text arry to java List?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jackson, gson

I am recieving a JSON payload from Postgres DB to my ApplicationServer as:

```
{
     "allAttributes" : {
     "name" : "some-name",
     "U_labels" : "{label26}"
     }
}
```

So I parse this json to convert it into a POJO in java using jackson json library.

However some fields like `U_labels` in Postgres are text array and `List<String>` in java. So `"U_labels" : "{label26}"` is expected to be        `"U_labels" : "[label26]".`

How can this mapping be achieved in jackson ??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe something like this:

```
List<String> stringList = mapper.readValue(jsonString, 
    typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, String.class));
```

Comment: This wil read for whole json string, but I will require to convert an individual key (`"U_labels"`) to convert to `List<String>`.

Comment: You have to achieve removing the braces by using String substitution. Since {U_labels} is not array in JSON.

Comment: @Popeye: Is there no other solution ? Maybe use of `objectMapper` could help ? As like this there will be some keys which will be deeply nested i would have to do string substitution there at the nested level.